# Crash after upgrade to androidX

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am using [BottomNavigationViewEx](https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx) library, and I upgraded androidX in my project.

```
BottomNavigationViewEx navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
Logger.d(TAG, "navigation == null " + (navigation == null));

if (navigation != null) {
    navigation.setCurrentItem(2); // Line 170: This make crash
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    navigation.setTextVisibility(false);

    navigation.enableAnimation(false);
    navigation.enableShiftingMode(false);
    navigation.enableItemShiftingMode(false);

    int iconSize = 36;
    navigation.setItemHeight(BottomNavigationViewEx.dp2px(this, iconSize + 16));
    navigation.setIconSize(iconSize, iconSize);
}
```

It generate below error log, and crashs.
How I can solve this ?

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mMenuView in class Lcom/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView; (declaration of 'com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView' appears in /data/app/com.calm_health.research-2/base.apk)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
>       at com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx.getField(BottomNavigationViewEx.java:802)
>       at com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx.getBottomNavigationMenuView(BottomNavigationViewEx.java:552)
>       at com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx.setCurrentItem(BottomNavigationViewEx.java:511)
>       at sports.calm_health.com.researcher.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:170)

Comment: What happened at MainActivity.java: line 170?

Comment: I don't think that it happened after upgrading to `AndroidX`. I faced this way before that. And I suppose it has something to do with this `navigation.enableItemShiftingMode(false);`?

Comment: Follow the issue on github. [See last comment](https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx/issues/126).

Comment: Have you read this line from the doc "AndroidX use new version，and add config into gradle.properties"?

Comment: did you add maven and jetpack libreries?

Comment: Search for android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView in  your project and replace it with androidx view.

Comment: @Giddy Naya said, https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx/issues/126 helps me, this is a correct answer.  I want to accept that comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx/issues/126

@Giddy Naya said, this is my answer

Answer (score 0):

This [library](https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx) is not updated and uses the **reflection** with the old class **`android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView`**.

It means that the library is looking for private fields and methods in the class provided by the old support design library. With the material components library (it is required by androidx) these fields and methods could be different or could change in the future.
As you can check in the error the library is looking for a `mMenuView` which is not present in `BottomNavigationView`.

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mMenuView in class Lcom/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView; (declaration of 'com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView' appears in /data/app/com.calm_health.research-2/base.apk) at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method) at

Answer (score -1):

put  below code in `gradle.properties` files.

`android.useAndroidX=true
 android.enableJetifier=true`

Comment: I think you haven't read the question clearly, androidx is already enabled in his project.

Comment: @ShivamYadav androidX may be enabled even without enabling the Jetifier

Comment: Then you should mention only this line  android.enableJetifier=true.